# Where to find the Java PComm HACL library

Tags: java, automation, ibm-pcomm, hacl

I've developped for my company multiple VB macro interacting with IBM Personnal Communication but I'd like to switch all those macro to Java for various reasons (mostly because I really hate working with VB and it is extremely slow)

While searching for solutions I've found many : JACOB.dll, x3270, f3270 and HACL. I haven't been able to found a way to make the first three work for me but I haven't been able to try HACL because I didn't found it

There is nothing on repos (maven, etc...), the documentation on ibm website is either missing, not existing or incomplete on the HACL subject...

Do you guys have any idea where I could find the libraries used by the OP of below link ?
[IBM PCOMM Automation using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893312/ibm-pcomm-automation-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

if you have Personal Communications installed on your machine, you can find under the root folder pcseclj.jar file if I recall correctly and you're good to go